# Yii2 DropdownList on relationated tables

Tags: yii2, dropdownlistfor

i have 3 tables

Events
*id
*idteacher

Teacher
*id
*person

Person
*id
*name1
*name2
*lastname1
*lastname2

How can i make a Dropdownlist on Events Form that shows the fullname of person but save the idteacher???

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idexpositor')->DropdownList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(TblExpositor::find()->all(),'id','idpersona'),
        ['prompt'=>'Seleccione el nombre del Expositor']
```

);?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a proper query .. like this (adapt the field and column name to your need)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'your_field_in_model')->DropdownList( 
        ArrayHelper::map(TblExpositor::find()->
            select('t.id as id,  concat(p.nama1, p.name2, p.lastname1, p.lastname2) as name')->
            from('Teacher t, Person p')->
            where('t.personeid = p.id')->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Seleccione el nombre del Expositor']
);?>
```